# Any way to get the AtomineerUtils addin to ignore __declspecs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, doxygen

I'm evaluating the AtomineerUtils addin (which allows Visual Studio to auto-enter doxygen comment blocks).

It misfires slightly when I have a class definition that has __declspec (dllexport) in it.  That is, instead of the class name appearing in the comment block it adds, it uses the word declspec.

Small annoyance, but annoyance nonetheless.

Anyone use this tool and have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow.... shot off an email to the Atomineer developer at the same time I posted this.  He just got back to me, his new version 5.97 fixes this!